# ROR + Detect how many ports are running for ruby application

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my ruby on rails project, I have to take `pull from sql-server to my mysql database.`

When I run my project on port `3000`, it makes system busy when I want to take pull.

I want such method or way which system can detect, how many ports are running for ruby application and how to close if it is not in use ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it something that should be done from UI? If not I would recommend `rake` task. When you start your project with `rails server`, it will only have one port and single thread, which is often enough for development. For multiple threads there are many options, `passenger` is one of them.

Comment: @Victor : Thanx for the reply. As i searched, founded that Passenger does not work with Windows. So please suggest any alternative of Passenger for windows server.

Comment: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2006/5/11/deploying-rails-on-windows-servers/ pretty old stuff though, if you have admin access on your Windows computer and enough memory I would recommend installing Linux on https://www.virtualbox.org/ and then you have plenty of choices, Passenger is just one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to understand exactly what you're asking for, but I'm assuming that when you are synchronizing databases,  the system becomes busy and you can't serve any pages.  This is a perfect example for the use of a background job that allows you to do tasks like this without affecting the rails application.  The two gems that come to mind that will allow you to do this is Delayed_job and Resque.  An outstanding screencast for doing this type of stuff is listed below as well.

http://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

https://github.com/defunkt/resque/

http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job

http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque